# How to fade out bottom when a wiget overflow ConstrainedBox?

Tags: flutter, constrainedbox

I wrote a list of card, and limit its max height. I want the card bottom fade when its height is over the limit, fade is not displayed when the limit is not exceeded.

The following is the effect I want

[image]

my code

```
Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
return CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
      (context, index) {
        return ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200),
          child: Wrap(
            children: [
              const Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text('test title'),
                  subtitle: Text(
                      'test \n test \n test test test test test test test test test testtest test test test test test test test '),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
      childCount: 10,
    ))
  ],
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you were meaning to constrain the height of the individual cards:

Using a `ShaderMask` you can achieve this effect:
[image: the effect]

```
CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (context, index) {
              return Wrap(
                children: [
                  ConstrainedBox(
                    constraints:
                        const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200),
                    child: Card(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text('test title',),
                        subtitle: ShaderMask(
                          shaderCallback: (bounds) => LinearGradient(
                            begin: Alignment.center,
                            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            colors: [Colors.white, Colors.transparent],
                          ).createShader(bounds),
                          child: Text('test \n test \n test test test test test test test test test testtest test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test testtest test test test test test test test ',),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
            childCount: 10,
          ))
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: great ！But I don't know which card exceeds the height limit。Is there any way to do it？